# Как авторизоваться на чужом сайте через vk api

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Добрый день
На одном сайте стоит авторизация через VK, как посредством php авторизоваться на нем?
Хотя бы натолкните, не прошу готовый код

Comment: намекаю: https://vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_user

Comment: ООоо, спасибо добрый человек

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Хмм... Но я же никак не узнаю их client_secret, я же хочу на их сайте зайти. Я получил code, а что дальше?